# Getting count of children with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

These are my entities:

```
public class Model {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] // EDIT: Forgot to add this in my sample code.
    public bool HasChildren { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChildModel> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Now what I want to do is, pull all the Model objects and set their HasChildren properties to true, if there are ChildModels related to the Model. This is how I do it now:

```
context.Models.Select(s => new Model {
    Id = s.Id,
    Name = s.Name,
    HasChildren = s.Children.Count() > 0
});
```

Which kind of feels like something is off with the way I project the result into a collection with the same type of the entity (Model).

Also I checked the generated query. The data is pulled in a single query which is nice but I wonder if there is a better way to do this with C#?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of count

```
context.Models.Select(s => new Model {
    Id = s.Id,
    Name = s.Name,
    HasChildren = s.Children.Any()
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this model definition:

```
public class Model {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool HasChildren => this.Children != null && this.Children.Count > 0;
    public ICollection<ChildModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

If you can not use C#6 features, than:

```
public bool HasChildren { get { return this.Children != null && this.Children.Count > 0; } }
```

EF Linq:

```
context.Models.Include(x => x.Children).ToList();
```

Comment: Doesn't this query load all the children also?

Comment: It will, but if you don't fill them to the Model class that will cause inconsistent state with your db. I suggest you not to do that, maybe you should create another model class, without the collection and map into it.

Comment: *it will* -- which makes this a bad idea.

Comment: If you dont want it, than yes.